# Marshalling time.Time to unix timestamp

Tags: json, go

I have a struct like so

```
type log struct {
    [...]
    Timestamp timestamp `json:"timestamp"`
}
```

and I want to have the Timestamp as unix timestamp instead of whatever go does by default (`2018-09-21T19:31:03.291Z`)

I've tried creating a custom type for that like this:

```
type timestamp struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t timestamp) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(strconv.FormatInt(time.Time(t.Time).Unix(), 10)), nil
}

func (t *timestamp) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(data[:]), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    t = &timestamp{
        time.Unix(i, 0),
    }
    return nil
}
```

but I'm always getting the error `can not unmarshal timestamp into *main.timestamp` when trying to read from the database.

```
for iter.Scan(&message.Text, &message.Timestamp) {

    userlogResult.Messages = append(userlogResult.Messages, message)
}
if err := iter.Close(); err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
}
```

It can't unmarshall the Timestamp here. https://github.com/gocql/gocql/blob/799fb0373110eaa4e2e71dd32a9b5903f80dca8f/helpers.go#L30 the issue is that it doesn't use the Unmarshall functions.

Edit: I've answered my own question.

Comment: Please provide the code for json where you are unmarshalling the data into timestamp.

Comment: The error says error on "Unmarshal" not on marshal , you need to implement Unmarshaller for unmarshal to work

Comment: I'm using echo's context.JSON for that here is the code: https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/context.go#L406

As for @SarathSadasivanPillai true I didn't notice that. I will try that

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai I've added the UnmarshalJSON method but sadly the error stays

Comment: You defined custom marshaling / unmarshaling for the `timestamp` type, but you don't use that in `log`. So either use `timestamp` in `log`, or define custom marshaling / unmarshaling on the `log` type.

Comment: @icza sorry that was just a bad copy paste on my part, I do actually use the timestamp type in log

Comment: Is it because you have a pointer receiver for the `UnmarshalJSON` method but use values everywhere else?

Comment: @IainDuncan no that's not it. I wrote that like the official implementation of time.Time.UnmarshalJSON looks like https://golang.org/src/time/time.go?s=37288:37335#L1240

It needs to be a pointer otherwise how am i going to modify the value.

Comment: I can't get this to fail!  However, I did notice that you set the pointer t to a new pointer which will be lost when you leave the method.  You actually need to dereference t and set the value in the location t points to.  Once done it seems to work for me, can you create an executable example where this fails?: https://play.golang.org/p/ht5PDO6PwD4

Answer (score 1):

here when assigning `&timestamp{..}` to t it is changing the pointer instead the value it is pointed to has to be chaged as follows

```
func (t *timestamp) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(data[:]), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *t = timestamp{
        time.Unix(i, 0),
    }
    return nil
}
```

Please find code  [here](https://play.golang.com/p/1lmEkUYCdOS)

**Edit**

Since you are failing to unmarshall when reading from Database it is not because of `json.unmarshalling` you have to implement **`sql.Scanner`**
if you are using sql

Please find the details here => [sql.Scanner](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner)

Comment: This wouldn't cause the error that the original post referred to though

Comment: Alright I can see that I did that wrong, even in the original Go implementation it is like you wrote. I fixed that. But it's not causing the error I'm having. The error still persists.

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai I've edited the original question. Sorry that I left out that part before.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is ok - apart from the code in your unmarshal. You don't show the code where you are Marshalling/Unmarshalling which is where the actual error is.

I have it working on the playground. [Golang Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/No0QIivkXxM)

Instead of this (which changes the pointer)

```
t = &timestamp{
  time.Unix(i, 0),
}
```

Change the value

```
t.Time = time.Unix(i,0)
```

Main function to use your structs

```
fmt.Println("First Log...")
l := log{Timestamp: timestamp{time.Now()}}
fmt.Println(l)

buf, err := json.Marshal(l)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("Marshalled to JSON...")
fmt.Printf("%s\n", buf)

var logCopy log
if err := json.Unmarshal(buf, &logCopy); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println("UnMarshalled from JSON...")
fmt.Println(logCopy)
```

Comment: Hmm yes, I have a similar working version on the playground now aswell. Okay so I know that code is good, but I'm still having issues in my program. I don't marshall it myself, I'm not even sure why the unmarshal error is thrown, the actual point where it is marshalled is here: https://github.com/labstack/echo/blob/master/context.go#L406 My code is just `return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, userlogResult)`

Answer (score 0):

Alright after confusing a lot of people here (sorry) and myself I've found a solution.

The marshalling to json works now only need to fix the gocql compatiblity like this:

```
var ts time.Time
for iter.Scan(&message.Text, &ts) {
    message.Timestamp = timestamp{ts}

    userlogResult.Messages = append(userlogResult.Messages, message)
}
```